# I used to use sumifs in excel to sum quantities that meet a certain criteria how can i perform the same concept in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
| Fiber1  | Color1  | Weight1|   | Fiber2  | Color2  | Weight2|         | Fiber  | Color  | TOTAL|
|CY-312   | 1  |    | 16 |       |CY-312   | 2 |    | 16 |                CY-312   | 2 |    | ....|
|CY-312   | 1  |    | 15  |      |CY-312   | 1  |    | 15  |
|CY-312   | 2  |    | 15  |      |CY-312   | 2  |    | 15  |
```

Please help get the total number of CY-312 Color in Access

Comment: Please help us, by NOT spamming TAG's that are irrelevant to the question

Comment: From the given sample, what do you expect for output? Why does the output show only Color 2? If you normalized data structure, would be much simpler to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT "CY-312" AS Fiber, Count(IIf([Fiber1]="CY-312" And [Color1]=2,1,Null))+Count(IIf([Fiber2]="CY-312" And [Color2]=2,1,Null)) AS Total
FROM Data;
```

Alternatively, normalize data structure with UNION:

```
SELECT Fiber1 AS Fiber, Color1 AS Color, Weight1 AS Weight, 1 AS Src FROM Data
UNION ALL SELECT Fiber2, Color2, Weight2, 2 FROM Data;
```

Then use that query as source for aggregate GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT Fiber, Color, Count(Src) AS Cnt
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Fiber, Color;
```